# BlazeDS: Server DTO method naming convention

Tags: java, spring, flex

I have the following field in Flex:

```js
[Bindable] public var zIndex:uint;
```

And I was trying to create the methods to process the calls in Java and I ran into a problem.

```java
1. public int getZIndex(); // Does not work.
2. public int getzIndex(); // Works.
```

I thought that the letter following the `get`/`set` was supposed to be capitalized? Is there a reason for this? I couldn't find any documentation.

I found an [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2948102/1762224) that states that the first one is the correct way to name an accessor/mutator.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer after some further investigation.

> [I]f the first two characters of the name are both upper case and if so leave it alone.

Section 8.8 of the [JavaBean Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf) by Sun states:

> **8.8 Capitalization of inferred names.**
>
> When we use design patterns to infer a property or event name, we need
>   to decide what rules to follow for capitalizing the inferred name. If
>   we extract the name from the middle of a normal mixedCase style Java
>   name then the name will, by default, begin with a capital letter.
>
> Java programmers are accustomed to having normal identifiers start
>   with lower case letters. Vigorous reviewer input has convinced us that
>   we should follow this same conventional rule for property and event
>   names.
>
> Thus when we extract a property or event name from the middle of an
>   existing Java name, we normally convert the first character to lower
>   case. However to support the occasional use of all upper-case names,
>   we check if the first two characters of the name are both upper case
>   and if so leave it alone. So for example,
>
> "FooBah" becomes "fooBah"
>         "Z" becomes "z"
>         "URL" becomes "URL"
>
> We provide a method Introspector.decapitalize which implements this
>   conversion rule.
>
> ```
> JavaBeans Introspection -- Sun Microsystems -- 10/12/97
> ```